# Why is this jQuery ajax click event firing multiple times?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have tried unbinding the click event, but it fires sometimes twice sometimes 5 times!! Getting a bit fed up now!

Code from `modal.asp`

```
$("input[name=add_associate]").live("click",function(){
    var addassociateID = $(this).attr("id")

    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/data/watchlist_save.asp',
       data: {m : 'share_watchlist_add', watchListID : <%=WatchListID%>, a : addassociateID},
       async:true,
       success: function(data) {
           $(".associate_users").load("/data/sub_watch_members.asp?watchListID=<%=WatchListID%>",
           {cache:false},function() {
               $(".search_note").html(data)         
               $(this).unbind('click').bind('click',handler);                                                                                                
           })
       },
       error: function(data){
           $(".search_note").html(data)
       }
    });     
})
```

**UPDATE**:
Basically I am calling the following code into `.associate_users`

```
<div id="associate_list">
    <div class="associate_record">
        <div class="left" style="padding:8px;"><img src="../imgs/nopic-m.png" style="width:30px;height:30px;" class="img_border" /></div>
        <div class="left" style="padding-top:15px;">5)Neil Burton</div>
        <div class="right" style="padding-top:10px;margin-right:5px;"><input type="button" class="btn-blue" name="add_associate" id="890" value="Add"></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

**FURTHER INFORMATION**:
This only happens when I fire the event, close the modal dialog then re-open it with a different `watchListID`

THE STRUCTURE OF DATA:

- **main.asp**: LOADS >
- **modal.asp**: modal.asp contains the jquery from above + two divs on this page with panel1.asp and panel2.asp data...
- **panel1.asp**: Contains the HTML above...
- **panel2.asp**: Contains nothing related... just pure HTML.

Comment: try putting a `return false;` at the end...

Comment: need html aso , we can easily find the problem , if you want to bind only once you can use .one

Comment: Is your selector add_associate matching more than one element? Maybe a clash with something in main.asp?

Comment: No its not, I removed the functionality to check and renamed the selector just in case...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have resolved this issue now, I was using

```
$(document).ready
```

in the loaded ajax content along with...

```
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

So I presume it was doubling up the "live" function!

Thank you so much for the responses.

Comment: I have upvoted all answers left because they are all right in the context of my problem.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem too. I just had bind a button with ajax call, and it fired 3 times. I just changed to good old onclick attribute, and everything fixed. Thanks again

Answer (score 17):

Watch your semicolons, make sure you end each command with one, will save you a headache later.

As for events bound by `live()`, they have to be unbound by calling `die()`. It has the same parameters as `unbind()`. Have a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/die/).

```
function ajaxHandler(){
    var addassociateID = $(this).attr("id");
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.die('click');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/data/watchlist_save.asp',
        data: {m : 'share_watchlist_add', watchListID : <%=WatchListID%>, a : addassociateID},
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            $(".associate_users").load("/data/sub_watch_members.asp?watchListID=<%=WatchListID%>",{cache:false},function(){
                $(".search_note").html(data);
                $this.bind('click',handler);
            });
        },
        error: function(data){
            $(".search_note").html(data);
            $this.live('click', ajaxHandler);
        }
    });     
}

$("input[name=add_associate]").live("click", ajaxHandler);
```

**Edit:** Forgot to add some important points. You have to unbind your live event right in the click handler and rebind it on error, just like **@stefan** suggested.

Also make sure you save the `this` object in a variable, as it's not pointing to your DOM element within the ajax callback function. Alternatively you can use the `context` property on your ajax request, check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: This didn't work... Its still firing two events which are showing in Firebug... Its starting to make me feel like I'm going insane now :D

Comment: @Chris Dowdeswell: I added further fixes, try it now.

Comment: Not sure how I am supposed to implement this? It doesn't work as is, is the $this.die('click') killing the function before it runs?

Comment: `die()` is the same as `unbind()`, but for events bound by `live()`. It doesn't kill it, just makes sure that if you click the button again before the request returns, it won't re-fire the event. If there is an error, if binds it back so you can try again. There was a typo though, I extracted your handler function into a function called `ajaxHandler` so it can be re-bound, but got the wrong name on the last line where I was binding it live, it's fixed now.

Comment: No, its still multiple times...
This only happens when I fire the event, close the modal dialog then re-open it with a different watchListID

Comment: What modal dialog? :) I think the code in your post is not enough to track that one down. Are you binding live events multiple times?

Comment: Sorry ill try and clarify, I am loading a page into a modal DIV.

The `DIV` has two sets of data via `$.load` with `DIV`s within that... so basically 2 levels of data...

Answer (score 16):

As I see, all you want to do is bind the event once and then die it. The latest jQuery versions have a .one() method, which will bind the event only once.

example:

```
$('#myDiv').one('click', function() {
    alert('clicked once...');
});
```

The next time you click, click event will not fire up.

More at http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 7):

This might be helpful - http://sholsinger.com/archive/2011/08/prevent-jquery-live-handlers-from-firing-multiple-times/

Comment: Personally I don't like the ending sentence of that article: "This (workaround) is probably the poor man's way of handling this problem and you should probably try to find a way to avoid double binding the event instead. *Who has the time for that?*". Would still prefer the mighty StackOverflow community to come up with the root cause explanation and clean solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can fix your problem in two ways:

1) Move your javascript code into main.asp, instead of modal.asp.

This will instantly fix your double-fire issue. You would have to modify your code slightly to pull the WatchListID value from some HTML inside modal.asp, rather than coding it directly as you are (since main.asp won't have that value yet.)

2) Keep your javascript code where it is, but stop using live events.

Use a simple ".click(function () {" call, instead of ".live('click', function() {".

You are reloading modal.asp each time the dialog opens, which means your javascript is being run every time it loads. If you keep your javascript code in modal.asp, then live() is probably not appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You are unbinding first afterwards the success. You need to unbind it in the click handler and then add it again onerror.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

```
    var liveActionRemove = $('#ajax-list-action-remove');

    $(liveActionRemove).live('click', function(){
        $(liveActionRemove).die('click');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/someurl',
            success: function(data){
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: this solved my problem, but I still don't understand, why... Sometimes it's just complicated :D

Answer (score 0):

```
function myEventHandler(e)
{
    if(e.handled !== true)
    {
      // put your payload here.
      // this next line must be here
      e.handled = true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Once an event is handled, the property handled can be set to true. So, check this whether it is still false before passing the control to your code. Found this [here](http://sholsinger.com/2011/08/prevent-jquery-live-handlers-from-firing-multiple-times/) and it worked for me.