# Why I am geting two time ajax callback result

Tags: ajax, time, callback, seconds

I am getting two time call back result result. if I write alert, I get alert two time. But it should one time.
I have no Idea about that. Can you please help.

```
  $('#kalfueduvg3').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var base_url = window.location.origin;
  var name = ""; 
  var location = "";
  var categories = "";
  document.getElementById("dd-selected-value").value="";
  var urlss = base_url+'/Views/help/mapsWithLoc.php'; 
  jQuery.ajax
       ({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: urlss, //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data: "f3y73d6d6dggs7ggk=" + name+"&locationgk="+location+"&categoriesgk="+categories, // Form variables

            success: function(ok_ka){
                      $("#kkk").html(ok_ka); 
                      return false;
                 }
             }); //end ajax function
             //return false;
       });//end main jQuery function here
```

I also used  async: false. But nothing happen. I get two time result.
Thanks,

Comment: why are you sending a long url string in your `data` parameter? and what does `mapsWithLoc.php` do?

Comment: mapsWithLoc.php FILE I write
<script>
alert("ok");
</script>
nothing else.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

As its shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120943/why-is-this-jquery-ajax-click-event-firing-multiple-times#answer-6189994)

I had the same problem using `$().click()`. I was using `$(document).ready()` as well as calling my script `<script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>` on the main page. This was probably using the `.live()` function inside of `.click()` twice.

Also I don't think async being true/false matters for why its being called twice.