# Jquery strange chaining of Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have a div called `project` and it is rendered with EJS

There several projects in the data for EJS, they are rendered by `forEach loop` - so several similar div appear.

The `project` div has `id` for identification in Jquery.

Further it has a `project.name` and `project.id` as a `data-*`

**The problem which I encountered:**

> If I don't reload the page as intended - first try works well and Element inner text get updated correctly.
> But on second try to change another project name both are changed to value of previous, so to say for both projects. In few words - new change overrides all previous. How is it possible?

> **Link to see how it looks in GIF**
> [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC1JG.jpg)
>
> > **Strange behaviour of chaining requests** [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5mH1.jpg)

---

```
  <%userData.forEach(function(project){%>
    <div class="project" id='project <%=project.id%>'>
      <div class="projectHeader">
        <div class="projectTitle">
          <h5 id="projectTitle <%=project.id%>" class="projectName">
            <%=project.name%>
          </h5>
       <div class="projectButtons">
        <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit Project Title">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editProjectTitleModal">
            <i id="editProjectName" class="editProject fas fa-pencil-alt" 
              data-name="<%=project.name%>" data-id="<%=project.id%>"></i>
          </a>
         </span>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

A simple modal is called when the `a` tag in `project` is clicked.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editProjectTitleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleformModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="" action="" method="">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Title</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input id="editProjectNameInput" autocomplete="off" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ].{1,25}" title="1 to 25 characters" class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea" placeholder="Enter new title" required></input>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" id="confirmEditProjectName" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Jquery event handler which serves to change `project.name`, at first sends it to database and ammend DOM with new name. So the database get the new data, but the page is not reloaded and `project.name` changed simultaneously.

It grabs `project-name` and `project-id` and sends Ajax regular post - method, on success - change element's inner text to `project-name`

---

```
// Edit Project Title by ID
$(document).on('click', "#editProjectName", function() {
  //Grab Id of the Project
  var editProjectId = $(this).attr('data-id');

 //Fill Modal input with current project.name
  var currentTitle = document.getElementById('projectTitle ' + editProjectId).innerText;
  $("#editProjectNameInput").val(currentTitle)
 
  var url = '/editProjectName';
  $('#confirmEditProjectName').on('click', function(event) {
  //Take new project name from updated modal input
    var newTitle = $("#editProjectNameInput").val();
  //If they are same - alert
    if (currentTitle === newTitle) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("New Title should be different")
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (newTitle.length > 1 && newTitle.length <= 25) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: {
            projectName: newTitle,
            projectID: editProjectId
          },
          success: function(result) {
     //Hide modal and change element inner text to new value
            $("#editProjectTitleModal").modal('hide')
        document.getElementById('projectTitle ' + editProjectId).innerText = newTitle;

      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    })
  }
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: First and foremost, IDs can't have spaces in them: `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`

Comment: Also, IDs have to be unique but in your loop you are using `id="editProjectName"`

Comment: @imvain2 How can I work this around? Maybe just by function onClick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I have found out that once the `on('click')` is called it is **On** until the page get reloaded.

Thanks to this Question and Answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/6121501/13541013

I figured out - `on('click')` event should be switched `off` by calling `$(this).off()` (`this` is the event)

In my case I had to make `$(this).off()` right after:

```
$(document).on('click', "#editProjectName", function() {
$(this).off() ... further code
```

And it has to be done for every single `on('click')` event in the script.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the space from the IDs and I changed from using the ID of `#editProjectName` to just using the class that is already on that object of `editProject`.

```
<%userData.forEach(function(project){%>
    <div class="project" id='project<%=project.id%>'>
      <div class="projectHeader">
        <div class="projectTitle">
          <h5 id="projectTitle<%=project.id%>" class="projectName">
            <%=project.name%>
          </h5>
       <div class="projectButtons">
        <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit Project Title">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editProjectTitleModal">
            <i class="editProject fas fa-pencil-alt" 
              data-name="<%=project.name%>" data-id="<%=project.id%>"></i>
          </a>
         </span>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>

// Edit Project Title by ID
$(document).on('click', ".editProject", function() {
  //Grab Id of the Project
  var editProjectId = $(this).attr('data-id');

 //Fill Modal input with current project.name
  var currentTitle = document.getElementById('projectTitle' + editProjectId).innerText;
  $("#editProjectNameInput").val(currentTitle)
 
  var url = '/editProjectName';
  $('#confirmEditProjectName').on('click', function(event) {
  //Take new project name from updated modal input
    var newTitle = $("#editProjectNameInput").val();
  //If they are same - alert
    if (currentTitle === newTitle) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("New Title should be different")
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (newTitle.length > 1 && newTitle.length <= 25) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: {
            projectName: newTitle,
            projectID: editProjectId
          },
          success: function(result) {
     //Hide modal and change element inner text to new value
            $("#editProjectTitleModal").modal('hide')
        document.getElementById('projectTitle' + editProjectId).innerText = newTitle;

      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    })
  }
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: @imvain2Thank you. I think I got it, in order to prevent situation like I had it is better to call event by class, right?

Comment: @imavain2 I updated my code with your snippet. I have figured out - that if I don't change name - but just click to edit and close input modal, post requests somehow get stacked one on another. So every logged ID of project is saved and at the moment when it's finally sent - all ID are affected and change their name. No clue how to proceed.